# Google Sheets drop down list won't stay in order

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-sheets

I've created a drop down list based on a defined range that consists of a list of musical intervals, represented by Roman numeral values. The list displays just fine the first time you open it but any time you open it after that, it displays with the most recent selections at the top of the list instead of displaying in the original order. The result is a list that is constantly in a different order, making it difficult to use. I realize this feature was probably added for convenience but I find it unnecessary and annoying. 
Is there a way to disable this feature?

Comment: The list is 
I,
ii,
iii,
IV,
IV+ / Vo,
V,
vi,
VI,
vii,
VII

Comment: Hmm...interesting.
well I guess I'll just have to leave it the way it is. It's not critical, just annoying.

Answer (score 3):

The current selection is always on top of the list and it appears that there is an attempt to reorder the list by related characters and/or alphabet.

The easiest way to ensure an identical list every time is to clear the contents of the cell then trigger the dropdown :)

Comment: Yeah, I discovered the same thing and it will work ok I guess. It's just irritating when devs force their idea of convenience on the consumer. Thanks for trying though!